# why i got this issue"Additional information: Cannot find the object "Device" because it does not exist."

Tags: c#

I try to write the device management tool, but i can not save new information to database back. My part of codes are below. Thanks a lot.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (checkValidDate() == 1)
        {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Location: " + comboBox1Selected + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Device Type: " + comboBox2Selected + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Device ID: " + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Serial Number: " + textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Warranty Exp Date: " + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Memo: " + textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                              "UserName: " + textBox5.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                              "Room Num: " + textBox6.Text, "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // user clicked yes
                MessageBox.Show("3333333333");
                addToDataBase();
            }
            else
            {
                // user clicked no
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // user clicked yes
    }
    else
    {
        // user clicked no
    }
}
```

Comment: I will post a simple example of how you check for Dialog results that will help you in getting started from there you can figure out the rest..also what does this code method look like `checkValidDate`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkValidDate() == 1)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
    if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
    { 
        //...write your code here that will save data to the database
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    { 
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```